# Non static inner class object creation without explicit enclosing instance

Tags: java, inner-classes

I read that an instance of an inner class cannot be created without an instance of outer class. But when I tried to create an instance of my inner class using it as an instance member of my outer class, it worked.

I understand that it is creating an inner object through a reference to my outer class object, but is it the right way to do it?

Below is my code snippet:

```
public class TestInner {
    private Nonstatic non = null;
    private static int access = 4;

    public class Nonstatic {
        void hello() {
            access = 90; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestInner outer = new TestInner();
        TestInner.Nonstatic innern= outer.new Nonstatic();
        System.out.println("Non static obj1 is "+innern);

        outer.testinnerObj();
    }

    public void testinnerObj() {
        non = new Nonstatic(); 
        System.out.println("Non static obj2 is "+non);
        non.hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing  "An instance of Inner class cannot be created without an instance of outer class". And that's exactly what you are doing.

First, you create an instance of the "outer" class:

```
TestInner outer = new TestInner();
```

Then, you create an instance of the "inner" class - it only lives
in the scope of outer:
`TestInner.Nonstatic innern= outer.new Nonstatic();`

So, the question maybe boils down to this: yes, you are creating the object in the static main method. But that does not matter, because you are using the syntax `outer.new`which creates it in the scope of outer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @B .M i am also creating an object of non static inner class in testinnerObj() method .. so will it be the right way also?

Comment: Yes, that's syntactically fine, because you are calling `outer.testinnerObj();` you are inside an instance method (an instance of the TestInner class).